# How to start a java applet from code?

Tags: java, applet

Let's suppose I have something like:

```
Applet myApplet = new MyApplet();
```

How can I invoke that applet in a way that a new window appears, and I am still able to access that MyApplet instance from that scope?
In general, I want to be able to write code like this:

```
class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Runner().run();
    }

    void run() {
        MyApplet myApplet = new MyApplet();
        myApplet.init();
        myApplet.doSomething();
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered elsewhere, for example, at http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1607.html

I found it via
https://www.google.ru/search?q=java+applet+%22as+application%22

Comment: That was a less than optimal example.  1) `start()` was never called (or `stop()` or `destroy()`). 2) The applet requests a parameter that would be missing because there is no stub. 3) The code sets a size on the frame, rather than a preferred size on the applet..

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an implementation of `java.applet.AppletStub` to your applet. The stub provides context information that simulates the behavior of a web browser.